# Cache implementation not working in github action

Tags: github, npm, github-actions

I've tried to follow the official documentation, several blogs and answers on stackoverflow but nothing helped me to find a solution for this problem.

With github-action I've created a script to run unit tests after every push is done in our github server. For now the project is in early stage, so our dependency list is quite short and `npm install` command is done quite quickly (around 40 seconds). Obviously in future we'll need to add more dependencies and we are expecting a serious increment of that time, so I've tried to implement the cache mechanism, but for some reason the process still need to download the dependencies and the time for that step still be pretty much the same.

Below there is the script I've used. Following the documentation online I've found 2 different options, I've tried both (once per time) but without luck.

```
name: unit

on:
  push:
    branches: ['*']
  pull_request:
    branches: ['*']

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '15'
          cache: npm
      # start option 1
      - name: Setup cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: app/node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('app/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-
      # end option 1
      # start option 2
      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        env:
          cache-name: cache-node-modules
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-
            ${{ runner.os }}-
      # end option 2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: run unit tests
        run: npm run test
```

Why the cache is not working? Am I doing some mistake in the script?